# Un grand récipient contient de l'eau, (un) liquide dont j'ai tant besoin

Tags: articles

Bonjour,

> Un grand récipient contient de l'eau, **liquide** dont j'ai tant besoin.

Est-ce qu'il faut mettre un article indéfini devant "liquide" ou les deux options sont possibles ?

Answer (score 1):

Tu peux mettre (ou ne pas mettre) ce que tu veux :

> Un grand récipient contient de l'eau, **liquide** dont j'ai tant besoin.

> Un grand récipient contient de l'eau, **un liquide** dont j'ai tant besoin.

> Un grand récipient contient de l'eau, **le liquide** dont j'ai tant besoin.

> Un grand récipient contient de l'eau, **ce liquide** dont j'ai tant besoin.

Comment: Merci, est-ce qu'il y a une différence entre la 2ème et la 3ème phrase (un / le) ?

Comment: Oui. Dans la deuxième, j'ai potentiellement besoin d'autres liquides alors que dans la troisième, c'est de celui-là en particulier dont j'ai besoin.

Comment: _Dans la deuxième, j'ai potentiellement besoin d'autres liquides_ --- Cela veut dire que j'ai besoin d'eau et d'autres liquides, par exemple éthanol, magma, etc. ? _dans la troisième, c'est de celui-là en particulier_ --- j'ai besoin du liquide qui se trouve dans ce récipient ? Ou j'ai besoin de n'importe quel récipient pourvu qu'il soit rempli d'eau ?

Comment: 2. Potentiellement, ça veut dire que j'ai peut-être besoin d'un autre liquide, mais ce n'est pas obligé. 3. Non, pas nécessairement l'eau qui est dans ce récipient, l'eau en général. J'ai besoin d'eau (et peu importe qu'elle soit dans un récipient ou pas, si elle coule d'un robinet, c'est sûrement bien aussi).